# Pull requests or similar in Boomla

Tags: merge, version-control, pull-request, boomla

In the Boomla Control Panel, I can fork websites and then merge (publish) them, which is a very good workflow. But how can I accept modifications from other users? They can clone my website, but how can I import their code with their modifications to automatically merge into my upstream?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for this yet.

The best you can do is to merge them manually by copying the files across branches. The upside is that in Boomla you have access to both branches simultaneously (not only the one checked out), thus it's fairly trivial to move the files that changed. You'd have to write a little script to show the diff between the branches, but that is fairly simple given the Boomla Filesystem.

That's definitely on the roadmap, we are just not there yet.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that code that I run on mydomain.com can access files in its branches too (e.g beta.mydomain.com)? What does "checked out" mean?

Comment: @Bernát Access files across branches: yes that's the plan. All branches of a website are present on the same machine making that feasible. That's not implemented yet, though there is a workaround to enable it: **mark the website as a tool**. Note that the concept of "tools" (a website used to edit others) is going to be phased out as it doesn't play well with a distributed architecture where the websites are not located on the same machine. We now install tools instead, like the IDE. Even in case it will be phased out, there will always be some way to copy files across branches.

Comment: @Bernát "checked out": sorry for not being clear, I meant that in traditional version control systems (like git), you have to check out a branch to get access to its filesystem. In Boomla, you have simultaneous access to all branches, thus you can also copy files across them.